# Jquery - Some problems with .remove()

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with my JQuery, I don't understand why the remove button don't work, could you help me please ? =)
So here is my code :

```js
$('.removeBook').on('click', function() {
  $('div').remove();
});

$('#createBook').click(function() {
  $('#list').append('<div>Hello' + '<button type="button" name="removeBook" class="removeBook">Remove</button>' + '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" name="createBook" id="createBook">Create</button>
<div id="list">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance if you can help me !

Comment: The element with class `removeBook` only exists _after_ clicking on `button#createBook`. One possible solution would be to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `on` function syntax is wrong. Since it is a dynamic element you should register the event on its container and to on function, Event should be first parameter and the second is selector.

And `("div").remove()` removes all the div. You should change your code to

```
$("#list").on('click',"button.removeBook", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6gd939kc/)